# Centering Input Elements - Bootstrap Panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have having a few problems, with what should be a simple task.

I have spent a good while trying to fix them, but no luck.

1. Centre the Input boxes within the div - tried this solution, (didn't work): http://jsfiddle.net/pjAHG/27/

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

2. Make the background image fill the full screen, only to the bottom of my timer div... if I use a solid colour, it fills the screen though :/ I have tried all the ways I can find online, but no luck.
3. Media query does not seem to change the size of the text/submit button.

If anyone could share some info, or help for these problems, I would be grateful.

Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVNZZO

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.input-group{
  max-width:80%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

and

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
 .btn-lg{
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    white-space:normal;
  }
    .lead-subtitle {
      color: #dbdbdb;
      text-decoration: underline;
      font-size: 1em;
      display:block;
    }
}
```

here is the [**updated pen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMrOxO).

Comment: @Nezz I'm glad I was able to help.. just mark this as the answer if it solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

1. centered the form element instead of the input fields as they are
   set to `display: table` by bootstrap anyway
2. this question doesn't make quite sense to me. I have added a sample image and it fills the whole bg, have a look
3. Bootstrap sets `white-space: nowrap` for the .btn class; I overwrote it for you

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXgPjZ

Comment: Great, button works now, only thing is, it doesn't shrink in size, but still fits in my div. Do you know how I can make it shrink? Cheers

Comment: EDIT: I fixed it, I added a font-size to the media query.